# How to save a command output to a variable in a Jenkinsfile Shell step?

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I have the following code:

```
...

stage('Some stage') {
    sh """
        #!/bin/bash
        CHECK=$(curl -sI https://somegithuburl.com)
        
        echo $CHECK
    """
}
...
```

And when the Jenkins job is executed it returns:

```
+ CHECK=
```

Do you know how can I save the output in a variable in the same way I would do in a Shell script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct way to pull the output and save as a variable:

```
export CHECK="$(curl -s https://somegithuburl.com)"
```

then you can use `$CHECK` as a variable

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
export CHECK=`curl -sI https://somegithuburl.com`;
echo $CHECK
```